# How do I fix this Akka unit test?

Tags: scala, akka, tdd, scalatest

I'm coming to Scala from Python and am trying to understand [test framework integration](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/testing-async.html#test-framework-integration) by modifying the examples in the documentation. I've pastebinned my [main.scala](https://pastebin.com/v0ycA6aq) file and [maintests.scala](https://pastebin.com/yZ1dRKmQ) file. The actor uses typed messages. It accepts a MoveRequest and replies with a MoveAction. IntelliJ complains that there is a type mismatch and that `probe.expectMessage(character.MoveAction("north"))` should be changed to a MoveRequest, which I don't understand because that is what should be probed, not expected. The compiler complains of a type mismatch. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach to testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TestProbe needs to be typed to which type of messages you are sending it.

```
final case class MoveRequest(message: String,  response: ActorRef[MoveAction])
```

Here the type of messages the response actor receives is MoveAction so in your test example you need a TestProbe of type MoveAction to test messages are sent to it.

```
  val probe = testKit.createTestProbe[MoveAction]()
```

As the test probe is not for the actor under test, it is for the actor in the MoveRequest message.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that fix later today and accept your answer if it works!

Comment: Thank you! I needed to change the line to: val probe = testKit.createTestProbe[character.MoveAction]()